# Can linker differentiate between template and non-template functions?

Tags: c++, templates

I came upon the rule that template friend functions need to be forward declared like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Rational;
template<typename T>
const Rational<T> operator* (const Rational<T>& lhs, const Rational<T>& rhs);

template<typename T>
class Rational {
public:
    friend
    const Rational operator *<> (const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
};

template<typename T>
const Rational<T> operator* (const Rational<T>& lhs, const Rational<T>& rhs)
{
  return Rational<T>();
}

int main(void)
{
  Rational<int> r;
  r = r * r;
  return 0;
}
```

rather than just writing

```
template<typename T>
class Rational {
public:
    friend
    const Rational operator * (const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
};

template<typename T>
const Rational<T> operator* (const Rational<T>& lhs, const Rational<T>& rhs)
{
  return Rational<T>();
}
```

And read an [explanation](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/template-friends.html) for it stating that:

> The snag happens when the compiler sees the friend lines way up in the class definition proper. At that moment it does not yet know the friend functions are themselves templates; it assumes they are non-templates ...
>
> ... this assumption causes the compiler to generate a call to the non-template functions, but the linker will give you an "undefined external" error because you never actually defined those non-template functions.

But in my understanding `r * r` should instantiate

```
const Rational<int> operator* (const Rational<int>& lhs, const Rational<int>& rhs);
```

How is that different from what becomes friend of `Rational<int>`?

Can compiler/linker differentiate between template and non-template functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rules of the language ([temp.fct]/2):

> A non-template function is not related to a function template (i.e., it is never considered to be a specialization), even if it has the same name and type as a potentially generated function template specialization.

With the second snippet, when `Rational<int>` is instantiated, the friend declaration in its body introduces a declaration of a *non-template* function:

```
const Rational<int> operator*(const Rational<int>&, const Rational<int>&);
```

A definition of this function does not exist in the program, and as a matter of fact, the `operator*` template is not even instantiated, because it loses overload resolution to the non-template `operator*`. So from the linker's point of view, there is no `operator*` at all.

But even if the `operator*` template had been instantiated, causing the compiler to emit a definition of

```
const Rational<int> operator*<int>(const Rational<int>&, const Rational<int>&);
```

this is a distinct function from the non-template `operator*` whose definition is actually required by `r * r`. If the linker allowed `r * r` to call the template specialization, it would be causing `r * r` to call a function that is different from the one that the standard says it should call. (However, technically, the linker is under no obligation to issue an error message, since this is a "no diagnostic required" error.)

That's why declaring the `operator*` template beforehand and ensuring that the friend declaration refers to that template (or a specialization thereof) is necessary.